# Drawing RAW buffer to CGBitmapContext

Tags: cocoa

I have a raw image buffer in the RGB format. I need to draw it to CGContext so that I get a new buffer of the format ARGB. I accomplish this in the following way:

Create a data provider out of raw buffer using `CGDataProviderCreateWithData` and then create image out of the data provider with the api: `CGImageCreate`.

Now if I write this image back to the CGBitmapContext using `CGContextImageDraw`.

Instead of creating an intermediate image, is there any way of writing the buffer directly to CGContext so that I can avoid the image creation phase?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a `CGBitmapContext` then you can get a pointer to the bitmap buffer using the `CGBitmapContextGetData()` function. You can then write your data directly to the buffer.

Comment: Yup, I am using CGBitmapContext, but my requirement is exactly the opposite. I have a RGB buffer which I want to convert it to RGBA / ARGB buffer.

Comment: In that case I don't think you have much option. You'll need to create a `CGImageRef` from your RGB data, and then draw it in an ARGB `CGBitmapContext`. Is there a reason you don't want to use a CGImage?

Comment: Ya, I need a new buffer from existing buffer, so is it necessary that I create an intermediate CGImage and convert it back (by using CGBitmapContext)?

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is to take RGB data with no alpha component and turn it into ARGB data with full opacity (alpha = 1.0 at all points), why not just copy the data yourself into a new buffer?

```
// assuming 24-bit RGB (1 byte per color component)
unsigned char *rgb = /* ... */;
size_t rgb_bytes = /* ... */;
const size_t bpp_rgb = 3;  // bytes per pixel - rgb
const size_t bpp_argb = 4;  // bytes per pixel - argb
const size_t npixels = rgb_bytes / bpp_rgb;
unsigned char *argb = malloc(npixels * bpp_argb);
for (size_t i = 0; i < npixels; ++i) {
    const size_t argbi = bpp_argb * i;
    const size_t rgbi = bpp_rgb * i;
    argb[argbi] = 0xFF;  // alpha - full opacity
    argb[argbi + 1] = rgb[rgbi];  // r
    argb[argbi + 2] = rgb[rgbi + 1];  // g
    argb[argbi + 3] = rgb[rgbi + 2];  // b
}
```

Comment: Its a good suggestion Jeremy, I have already tried it but it turns out to be too slow. I was just wondering if there are any efficient ways to achieve this. Seems that the only possible way is just as I am doing right now and the one Rob suggested. Create an image and draw it back to the context.

Comment: Be sure to test speed under the release configuration, with all compiler optimizations applied, rather than the debug configuration. If it's still too slow, you could try (in likely order of difficulty): unrolling the loop by hand; reading and writing words rather than bytes; using vector instructions; offloading the work to the GPU.